# I am creating an image slider and when the image is set back to the other side of the screen it wont continue moving

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

So my idea was that i move 4 images by 150px per click to the left and when an image reaches the end of the screen it gets to the other side so it could repeat the circle. But once the image actually gets on the right side of the screen it stops moving on click.

My Code

`// VARIABLE FOR THE MENU SLIDER

```
var move = 150;
// MEAL ITEM SLIDER IMAGES 
var imgFood1 = document.getElementById('imgFood1')
var imgFood2 = document.getElementById('imgFood2')
var imgFood3 = document.getElementById('imgFood3')
var imgFood4 = document.getElementById('imgFood4')
imgFood1.style.position = "relative"
imgFood2.style.position = "relative"
imgFood3.style.position = "relative"
imgFood4.style.position = "relative"

function menuSlider(){
    // GETTING THE POSITION OF THE IMAGES
    var positionImg1 = imgFood1.getBoundingClientRect();
    var positionImg2 = imgFood2.getBoundingClientRect();
    var positionImg3 = imgFood3.getBoundingClientRect();
    var positionImg4 = imgFood4.getBoundingClientRect();
    // MOVING THE IMAGES 
    imgFood1.style.right=move+"px"
    imgFood2.style.right=move+"px"
    imgFood3.style.right=move+"px"

        if(positionImg4.left > 0 ) {
            imgFood4.style.right=move+"px"
        }else {
            imgFood4.style.left="500px"
        }

    // INCREMENTING THE MOVE VALUE FOR THE NEXT FUNCTION CALL
    move+=150

}

button.addEventListener("click", menuSlider);
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code bellow. Hope it fits your case.

```js
var move = 150;
// MEAL ITEM SLIDER IMAGES
var imgFood1 = document.getElementById('imgFood1')
var imgFood2 = document.getElementById('imgFood2')
var imgFood3 = document.getElementById('imgFood3')
var imgFood4 = document.getElementById('imgFood4')
imgFood1.style.position = "absolute"
imgFood1.style.left = 0;
imgFood2.style.position = "absolute"
imgFood2.style.left = '150px';
imgFood3.style.position = "absolute"
imgFood3.style.left = '300px';
imgFood4.style.position = "absolute"
imgFood4.style.left = '450px';

function menuSlider(){

    var arrayOfImages = [imgFood1,imgFood2,imgFood3,imgFood4];
    for(let i = 0; i < arrayOfImages.length; i++) {
      var positionImg = arrayOfImages[i].getBoundingClientRect();
      var leftValue = parseInt(arrayOfImages[i].style.left);
      if(positionImg.x < window.innerWidth) {
        arrayOfImages[i].style.left = leftValue + move + "px"
      }else {
        arrayOfImages[i].style.left = '0px'
      }

    }

}

document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener("click", menuSlider);
```

```css
#myButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
}

.images-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-container">
      <img id="imgFood1" src="https://i.imgur.com/30XsebB.jpg" alt="cat" height="150" width="150"/>
      <img id="imgFood2" src="https://i.imgur.com/30XsebB.jpg" alt="cat" height="150" width="150"/>
      <img id="imgFood3" src="https://i.imgur.com/30XsebB.jpg" alt="cat" height="150" width="150"/>
      <img id="imgFood4" src="https://i.imgur.com/30XsebB.jpg" alt="cat" height="150" width="150"/>
 </div>
 <button id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Scroll</button>
```

Comment: @Nenad you're welcome, can you mark the question as answered so others know it's solved?